#bootbox Pressing enter two times, calls the callback function two times when i use bootbox.dialog async submit form?
When you press enter two times really fast the callback function is called two times.
if you press more times its called more times.
here is my bootbox code:
<div id="test">

</div>

var count = 0;
bootbox.dialog({
              title: 'test',
              message: '<form action="https://catfact.ninja/fact">test</form>',
              buttons: {
                      success: {
                      label: 'ok',
                      className: 'btn-success',
                      callback: function () {
                       var close = false;
                       var submitForm = $(this).find('form');
                       submitForm.ajaxSubmit({
                         block: true,
                         dataType: 'json',
                         async: false,
                         success: function (result) {
                          console.log('res', result)
                          $('#test').append('<br>' + (++count));
                           if (result.fact) {
                            close = true;
                         } else {
                           close = false;
                        }
                      },
                    error: function (err) {
                  close = false;
               }
             })
           return close;
        }
     }
   }
 })

Example with code: https://jsfiddle.net/jeffier_wan/4q7hdbgp/20/
I am using Chome 50.0.2661.94 m , also tested with Firefox 43.0.1
i wanna only excute one time when i press more times, click it then cancel disabled button until the api send the result.
i try to set submit button disabled when i click, but find its not work for me.
anyone knows how to fix it?
here is some issues from bootbox github:
https://github.com/bootboxjs/bootbox/issues/514
https://github.com/bootboxjs/bootbox/issues/674

By "fix", I assume you mean "how do I do this?" - this isn't a bug in Bootbox.
That being said, a few changes will yield the behavior I think you're after. First, store a reference to the dialog which Bootbox creates:
let myDialog = bootbox.dialog({ /* your code */ }});

Then, add another class to the "submit" button, to make it a bit easier to target (I'm using submit-btn):
let myDialog = bootbox.dialog({
  title: 'test',
  message: '<form action="https://catfact.ninja/fact">test</form>',
  buttons: {
    success: {
      label: 'ok',
      className: 'btn-success submit-btn', // <--- here

Then disable the button in your callback:
let myBtn = myDialog.find('.modal-footer .submit-btn');

myBtn.prop({ disabled: true });

Putting it all together:
let count = 0;
let panel = $('#test');

let myDialog = bootbox.dialog({
  title: 'test',
  message: '<form action="https://catfact.ninja/fact">test</form>',
  buttons: {
    success: {
      label: 'ok',
      className: 'btn-success submit-btn',
      callback: function() {
        let myBtn = myDialog.find('.modal-footer .submit-btn');

        myBtn.prop({ disabled: true });

        count++;

        panel.append('<br>' + count);
      
        let submitForm = myDialog.find('form');
        submitForm.ajaxSubmit({
          block: true,
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
          success: function(result) {
            console.log('res', result);

            if (result.fact) {
              myDialog.modal('hide');
            } else {              
              myBtn.prop({ disabled: false });
            }
          },
          error: function(err) {
            myBtn.prop({ disabled: false });

            console.error(err);
          }
        });
        
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
});

